# Magento2 Stop order from placing if payment error occurs

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I am facing a strange issue where the order gets placed & details are displayed in admin even when I get the following error.

> Status Code 101 - Invalid Credit Card Number - Description: Normal

How can I stop this?

Comment: This error related to your payment method.

Comment: @AmitSaini yes I am using secure pay...

Comment: "If credit card number contains characters other digits, or bank does not recognize this number as a valid credit card number."
This is detailed info of this error code as per securepay user guide.

Comment: https://www.securepay.com.au/SecurePay_Response_Codes%20V1.1.pdf

Comment: Please enable sandbox mode for securepay payment method in magento admin and then try with test credit card details.

Comment: @AmitSaini Yes I am entering an invalid credit card details purposely .. My issue is if invalid CC details are entered order shouldn't be placed, in my case it is getting placed with a blank order status

Comment: Ok @Arjun, you need to debug securepay module. I think this module's functionality is that the first order placed then payment work start and after payment, they only change order status.